# Redemption.dll regsvr32 failed

Tags: outlook-redemption

Since we updated MS Office 2016 to version 1703 (Build 7967.2139), all the users having issues with registering Redemption.dll using regsvr32. It just doesn't give any error while running the regsvr32 command. We ran the command in admin mode. I looked at the events in Application log, and found below information:

```html
Faulting application name: regsvr32.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d7fb
Faulting module name: olmapi32.dll, version: 16.0.7967.6531, time stamp: 0x58f7803c
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0012c733
Faulting process id: 0x4294
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2c4413ac3ef95
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\olmapi32.dll
Report Id: dade8820-84eb-46a0-9e19-2d5f9c4d9f7d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Is there anyone who is having this problem and found a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using Redemption 5.12 or at least 5.11. Older versions of Redemption (released before Outlook 2016 was available) do not support Outlook 2016.